# Retrieve Hive Data as JSON document using Java REST API

Tags: rest, hadoop, d3.js, hive

I am trying to build a front end visualization screen and the backend data is in Hive. I am trying to develop a REST API that fetches data from Hive into JSON format from where I can use any D3.js or other libraries to display data.

I am new to this so need an advice as to which is the best approach to do this and in case you already have any examples about how to do this. Appreciate your response. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store your output in Json format then you can use Avro. Hadoop supports Avro in which files are of Json format.

For this you can refer to "Hadoop : The definitive Guide by Tom white " in this book there is a whole chapter dedicated to Avro. But if you are in hurry you can directly skip to, section Avro mapreduce , example  12.2 ( use 4 edition of book available online ) 
There he had explained how to save a file in Json output.